# Guava, Files.readLines() and white space

Tags: java, string, file-io, guava

I have the following code which utilises Guava's Files.readLines() method:

```
List<String> strings = Lists.newArrayList();
final File file = new File(filePath);
if (file.isFile()) {
  try {
    strings= Files.readLines(file, Charsets.UTF_8);
  }
  catch (IOException ioe) {}
}
else {
  // File does not exist
}
```

Once I have my List of String I'd like to test to see if a current String which I am looking at was in the file.

```
String myString = "foo";
if (strings.contains(myString)) {
  // Do something
}
```

However, I'd like to make the code tolerant to the original file contain leading or trailing spaces (i.e. `" foo "`).

What is the most elegant way of achieving this?

Comment: Tolerant how? Are the lines arbitrary, or just single words? Sounds more like you'd want to use a regex or looser predicate than a simple "contains". Guava has functional-style utils for this exact reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only alternative to tskuzzy's approach that I can think of is as follows:

```
List<String> trimmedLines = Files.readLines(file, Charsets.UTF_8,
  new LineProcessor<List<String>>() {
    List<String> result = Lists.newArrayList();

    public boolean processLine(String line) {
      result.add(line.trim());
    }
    public List<String> getResult() {return result;}
  });
```

Comment: `processLine(String line)` must return a boolean? Can I just add `return true`?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to iterate over whole file (if you want to know only if line is in file), use [`Files.readLines(File file, Charset charset, LineProcessor<T> callback)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#readLines%28java.io.File,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20com.google.common.io.LineProcessor%29)

```
public final class Test {

  /**
   * @param args
   * @throws IOException
   */
  public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    test1("test");
  }

  static void test1(final String lineToTest) throws IOException {

    final Boolean contains = Files.readLines(new File("test.txt"), Charsets.UTF_8, new LineProcessor<Boolean>() {
      Boolean containsGivenLine = false;

      @Override
      public Boolean getResult() {
        return containsGivenLine;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean processLine(final String line) throws IOException {
        if (line.trim().equals(lineToTest)) {
          containsGivenLine = true;
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      }
    });

    System.out.println("contains '" + lineToTest + "'? " + contains);
  }
```

Given file:

```
  test  
me   
   if  
 you want!
```

it outputs true.

Comment: I like the approach but I'd prefer to have a List of trimmed String so I can reuse.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `trim()` method, which removes leading and trailing whitespace.

```
boolean contains = false;

for(String s : strings) {
    if(s.trim().equals(myString)) {
        contains = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(contains) {
    // do something
}
```

If you also want case-insensitivity, then you can also use `toLowerCase()`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought there may be a way of avoiding having to loop though the Strings like this. Though I guess this is what contains() does anyway?