# Ensuring that empty lines in text file are not added to list?

Tags: java, string, list, file, methods

I have a `Java method` (below) that checks a `text file` for `string` values then adds then to a `list`:

```
 public List<String> iterateTextFile(String filePath) {

        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            lines = Files.readLines(new File(filePath), Charset.forName("utf-8"));
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lines;
    }
```

However, this method will add *blank lines* e.g.: `""` to the `ArrayList` as well. I do not want this?

How can I add validation so that this does not occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before returning remove the empty elements that is :-

```
for(int i =0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
  if(list.get(i).equals("")) {
    list.remove(i);
  }
}
return list;
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter them:

```
public List<String> iterateTextFile(String filePath) {

        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath)).stream().filter(str -> !str.trim().isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lines;
    }
```

For pre-stream java versions you can do it like this (you go from last position to 0, so you don't have refills):

```
public List<String> iterateTextFile(String filePath) {

        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            lines = Files.readLines(new File(filePath), Charset.forName("utf-8"));
            eliminateEmptyStrings(list);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lines;
    }

    private void eliminateEmptyStrings(List<String> strings) {
    for (int i = strings.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       if (strings.get(i).trim().isEmpty()) strings.remove(i);
    }
}
```

**Note:** add asserts to check for nulls or you could end up with some NPE or other not controlled exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer: just modify the 'LineProcessor' to filter out the empty lines!

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11017585/1410512)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like

```
List<String> lines = new LinkedList<>();
int lineCounter = 0;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
while(scanner.hasNext()){
    String currentLine = scanner.nextLine();
    lineCounter++;
    if(currentLine!=null && currentLine.length()==0){
        System.out.println("Skipping empty line number:" + lineCounter);
    }else{
        lines.add(currentLine);
    }

}
```

See, the use of a counter variable to indicate if this is working correctly or not. Well, this code obviously comes with a `FileNotFoundException` to be taken care of.